# Reposition of UIView with subviews not working when resizing a sibling view with auto layout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have two views that I am trying to resize/reposition with auto layout.

[image]

I have set the following constraints:

Red view:

- Top space to superview: 0
- Trailing and leading space to superview: 0
- Height equals: 100

Blue view:

- Top space to red view: 0
- Trailing and leading space to superview: 0
- Height equals: 100

Both views are subviews of `self.view`. And the blue view has a `UILabel` as a subview (not shown in the screenshot).
What I want to do is to change the size of the red view (with animation) and have the blue view follow that size change:

```
- (IBAction)resizeButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        if (sender.selected) {
            self.redViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100; // collapse
        }
        else {
            self.redViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200; // expand
        }
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

The animation works and the size of the red view changes. However, the blue view never changes position, even though it has a constraint to the bottom of the red view.

I have tried adding `[self.blueView layoutIfNeeded]` and even both `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` and `[self.blueView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`, but it made no difference.

The weird thing is that if I remove the label from the blue view everything works as expected. As soon as I add it again the blue view remains static. It makes no difference if the label has any constraints or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete implementation:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint* redViewHeightConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-  (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView* redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView* blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(redView, blueView);

    [self.view addSubview:redView];
    [self.view addSubview:blueView];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[redView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[blueView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

    self.redViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:nil
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                               multiplier:0
                                                                 constant:100];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.redViewHeightConstraint];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:redView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:0
                                                           constant:100]];

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"label";
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [blueView addSubview:label];

    [blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

    [blueView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:blueView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(resizeButtonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Expand" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Collapse" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:blueView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:30]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];



}

- (IBAction)resizeButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        if (sender.selected) {
            self.redViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100; // collapse
        }
        else {
            self.redViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200; // expand
        }
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered the same problem.
I solved it by saving the frame of the label before the animation block (`CGRect frame = self.label.frame;`) and in the animation block set the frame of the label again (`self.label.frame = frame;`)

Comment: I would really like to avoid manipulating frames as we are not supposed to do that when using auto layout. Furthermore, I would like to understand the cause of my issue here.

Comment: How do you add the label on the blueView? What constraints do you add?